# Training the "tesseract ocr" with predefined font images

Tags: pattern-matching, ascii, ocr, tesseract, training-data

I am trying to make OCR recognition of ASCII strings from the image. I am using Tesseract3 library, but I am having a little bit of the problem with correct recognition, so I need to train it with new character set (which is specific).
I already discovered this HOW-TO: [TrainingTesseract3](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3), but the tutorial has some unnecessary procedures which I do not need, because of the simplicity of my image test set.
My image data set comprises only **1 liners**, where each of the ASCII characters is the **same** in all images (no rotation, no scaling), but has variable distance (only horizontal) between characters in the line.

How can I use font images to train the recognition algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

Sir just get what particular font you want to train then write letter or number in notepad (I think 5 reps/letter) save as tiff file. If you want to train it use any of this https://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/ or http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html.

Comment: Thank you, I have already discovered jTessBoxEditor, but did not know how to properly deal with training process, while I already had only exact images of each font, and even that those were smaller than recommended (only _9x6_px). Thank you for your proper guidance.

Comment: If your hard to train it using jTessBoxEditor.. Just follow instruction on tesseract3 by using serak trainer then you will find how easy it is.

Comment: Is there a Serak trainer for Ubuntu?